# Adding module configuration settings to config.php

Tags: add-on-development, configuration-variables

As here, I'm looking to [set some variables for a module](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/13832/how-can-i-add-configurable-variables-to-my-add-on). Creating a [DB table seems a bit overkill](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/3632/am-i-able-to-store-my-own-module-settings-in-an-ee-table) (or maybe it's really not). I've noticed that the Simple Commerce Module does two things: creates DB tables *and* adds to the `config.php` file. With the second method, it's using `ee()->config->_update_config`.

I cannot find any documentation on `_update_config`. It seems straight-forward enough, but I'm wondering if there's a reason I shouldn't use it.

In short, I'm looking to package a module for distribution, and I don't want to make it more complicated than it needs to be (e.g., I don't want to have to install an extension *and* a module). Is adding variable/settings to `config.php` a good idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would store the settings in 'settings' column in 'exp_modules' table.

It does not exist in early versions of EE 2.x, so in your upd.my_module.php in function install() add

```
    $this->EE->load->dbforge(); 

    //----------------------------------------
    // EXP_MODULES
    // The settings column, Ellislab should have put this one in long ago.
    // No need for a seperate preferences table for each module.
    //----------------------------------------
    if ($this->EE->db->field_exists('settings', 'modules') == FALSE)
    {
        $this->EE->dbforge->add_column('modules', array('settings' => array('type' => 'TEXT') ) );
    }
```

and example save_settings() function can look like this

```
function save_settings()
{

    if (empty($_POST))
    {
        show_error($this->EE->lang->line('unauthorized_access'));
    }

    unset($_POST['submit']);

    $this->EE->db->where('module_name', 'My_module');
    $this->EE->db->update('modules', array('settings' => serialize($_POST)));

    $this->EE->session->set_flashdata(
        'message_success',
        $this->EE->lang->line('preferences_updated')
    );

    $this->EE->functions->redirect(BASE.AMP.'C=addons_modules'.AMP.'M=show_module_cp'.AMP.'module=my_module'.AMP.'method=settings');
}
```

Comment: I’m a little late to this party, but this just recently came up on the EE Slack and I just want to make note that this is a really, really, really bad idea. Sorry. I know I’m coming in here and and raining on your parade. But you should never, ever, ever, ever, modify core tables. If EllisLab ever added a settings column themselves, the updater would throw a fatal error. Another add-on might get the same idea and try to do it. If you (add-on) did not create the table and don’t have sole control over it, you should not mess with the structure. Create your own table is the best bet.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

[master config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) where you can set environment variables and custom global variables but this isnt done via control panel. In fact, quite the opposite happens. You set a variable in master config and it cant be changed in control panel. Handy when you have certain settings that need to be locked down.

[stash](https://github.com/croxton/Stash/wiki) and set user or site variables via an input form. Save variable and define an appropriate refresh period.

Comment: Neither option would work for me; as an example, I'm trying to save an Amazon Associate ID--that's not the kind of thing that changes nor do I want to constantly force the user to re-enter it. I suppose the easy way out is to tell people to add these variables directly to `config.php`, but why?

Comment: Is that a unique value per member? If so http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/custom_member_fields_edit.html

Comment: Or you can use this to edit/add config items. http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/admin/config_editor.html

Comment: I'm trying to create a packaged module for distribution. I want the control panel access so people can add their own variables *without* having to deal with `config.php`. Let me clarify my question a bit.

Comment: Sorry, i was responding to this comment... "I don't want to make it more complicated than it needs to be (e.g., I don't want to have to install an extension and a module)." I think you will need to make a mini module to do this.

Comment: I *am* making a module. I want to know if it's a good idea to saving settings to `config.php`. I suppose it really doesn't matter.